# add new column to dataframe given multiple conditions second dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, apply

I'm passing a multi-conditional lambda function via the apply method to a second dataframe whose values, if met with relational values of the first dataframe, should add an independent column from the second dataframe to the first dataframe.

In this case, I would want to check if the author of `DF2` matches with author of `DF1`, and if the date in `DF2` falls in between the `start` and `end` dates of DF1. If all conditions are met, then add `source` to `DF1`.

Here is my code thus far. Conditions seem to check out, but runtime seems to question that, as I'm not getting any output whatsoever.

```
def add_source(x):
    source_match = master_source.apply(lambda y: y['source'] if
                                                    (y['viewed_date'] >= x['start_date'] 
                                                     and y['viewed_date'] <= x['end_date'] and 
                                                    x['market'] == y['market']) 
                                                    else None, axis=1)
    source_match = source_match.dropna(axis=0, how='all')
    if source_match.empty:
        source_match = np.nan
    else:
        source_match = source_match.to_string(index=False)
    return source_match
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A better approach is to create a function that you'll use inside an apply like so:

```
def add_source(row):
    matches = df2[
        (df2['author'] == row['author']) &
        (df2['date'].between(row['start'], row['end']))
    ]

    source = matches['source'].values[0] if len(matches) > 0 else None

    row.loc['source'] = source

    return row

df1 = df1.apply(add_source, axis=1)
```

More streamlined logic as yours (and more readable form of the lambda function you made). The function loops row by row through `df1`, compares specific values from `df1` with specific values in `df2` (i.e. those with the same `author` and whose `date` falls between the `start` and `end`. returns the first match (which is what the `.values[0]` means) if there is a match (which is what `len(matches) > 0` is for) else returns `None`.

Then assign that value to the row as a column named `source`.

Another approach is to just merge and then just create a new column like so:

```
merged_df = pd.merge(
    left=df1,
    right=df2,
    how=left,
    on='author'
)

merged_df.loc[:,'new_source'] = merged_df.apply(
    lambda row: row['source'] if row['date'].between(row['start'], row['end']),
    axis=0
)
```

The only downside of this approach (that I can see) is duplicates.

Comment: with the function i'm getting `IndexingError: ((slice(None, None, None), 'source'), 'occurred at index 0')` does this have to do with each dataframe index starting as 0?

Comment: can you try adding a print(matches) inside the function to see what matches come up for each row?

Comment: print() isn't showing result, as it's now throwing me `KeyError: ('market', 'occurred at index market')`

Comment: it looks like you're using different dataframes from the examples given. Could you edit question to give examples of dataframes of `df1` and `df2` with more than 1 column?

Comment: edited answer. edits are:

1.) use `axis=1` when using apply instead of `axis=0`
2.) remove `[:` from `row.loc[:,'source']`. instead use `row.loc['source']`